# Quickblox.sdk GetBaseSession() method throws "nonce is required" error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, quickblox

I have used quickblox chat sdk in my old xamarin.forms project. I know that quickblox is not supporting xamarin now, but old sdk was working fine till now, but from last week I am getting this error.

Code:

```
var baseSesionResult = await Provider.QbProvider.GetBaseSession();
```

When I am calling `QbProvider.GetBaseSession()` it throws below error:

```
CONTENT: {"errors":{"base":["nonce is required"]}}
```

I have tried different methods available in sdk but none is working. Any one know how to fix this error?

Comment: Sounds like a missing dll or nuget reference. Have you checked if your nugets have updates? Anything helpful at [quickblox's github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/)? I don't know anything about quickblox, but I'll mention that you shouldn't need it to "support xamarin" - if you only refer to it in your android  and ios projects. If you need access from your forms project, you can still access it, like any platform-specific code, via a xamarin forms "dependency service". (Maybe its only the "Forms" support that is a problem.)

Comment: No, it's not because if missing dll. And it's workig fine from Xamarin.Forms as we have nuget for it. But it's not working now that's the problem. And yes, I have check quickblox documents on github and it's official site as well but not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is Nikolay from QuickBlox support.

Please add "" symbols around nonce and timestamp values and check if the issue is resolved.
The same information is mentioned in our documentation: https://docs.quickblox.com/reference/authentication#create-session

We released a patch for authentication that improves validation according to our documentation.
Hence, the issue is caused by incorrect implementation in the application that is why the server has started showing errors for submitted requests.

Comment: Hello Nikolay, Yes I have read the document but I am using sdk of Quickblox and it's not asking for time stamp or nonce values. So from where do I have to pass it?

Comment: Please let me know the version of the SDK. 

Also, I can suggest using new versions of the SDKs that you can find here:
https://github.com/QuickBlox

Please be notified that we do not provide support with other SDKs.

Comment: I am using Quickblox.sdk version 1.2.7

Comment: Unfortunately, it is deprecated and we do not provide support with it.

Please consider using new SDKs.